# cordova not defined for file opener2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, fileopener2

I have been trying to open pdf on an ionic app using file opener2 Cordova plugin but it's not working and is showing errors with Cordova not defined(but Id id inject the ngCordova module at app.js

```js
    $scope.gotoPDF1 = function () {
      cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        'pdf/main.pdf',
        'application/pdf', {
          error: function (e) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
          },
          success: function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');
          }
        }
      );
    }
```

```html
        <div class="col col-60" style="margin-left:8%" ng-click="gotoPDF1()">
```

Comment: Do other plugins work? Did you run your app in the browser or on a device / simulator?

Comment: Also, ngCordova is obsolete. https://github.com/ionic-team/ng-cordova/issues/1452

Comment: I first tried   window.open('pdf/main.pdf');

Comment: But it only worked on browser and not on mobile device

Comment: @D.Simon The fileopener2 plugin didn't work on either browser nor on device